# Были ли нормы использования тире другими во времена СССР?

Tags: тире

На плакате (https://i.redd.it/0ltfq01asiwz.jpg) стоит тире между подлежащими, выраженными существительными, и сказуемым, выраженным глаголом:

> НАРОД, АРМИЯ, СТАЛИН — СПАСЛИ ТЕБЯ, МОСКВА!

Насколько я понимаю, в современной трактовке тире этого быть не должно.

Соответственно возникает вопрос, почему на плакате написано так: было ли это обусловлено современной нормой, или исключительно стилистическими соображениями?

Comment: Слово "современной" в вопросе употреблено неверно. Корректно: "обусловлено нормами того времени".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

НАРОД, АРМИЯ, СТАЛИН — СПАСЛИ ТЕБЯ, МОСКВА!

Искусство играло важнейшую роль в мобилизации советского общества в годы Великой Отечественной войны. Особое место в пропаганде занимали политические плакаты, которые имели ряд специфических свойств: постоянство обращения, краткость и доходчивость призыва, четкость и яркость изображения.

Я не могу сказать "за все нормы" и правила постановки тире, но мне кажется, что в этом плакате тире стоит вполне оправданно.

1. Посмотрите, в тексте нарушен стандартный порядок слов. В обычном предложении он [порядок] был бы таким: **Москва, тебя спасли народ, армия, Сталин!**
2. Слова "НАРОД, АРМИЯ, **С**ТАЛИН" написаны буквами одного размера (без заглавной "С" в фамилии). Этим, как мне кажется, в плакате хотели показать, что народ, армия и Сталин — это неразрывное целое, единая сила.
3. Я думаю, что здесь имеет место интонационное тире, которое можно поставить между любыми членами предложения. Оно на письме замедляет чтение в ожидании следующих слов, заставляет обратить на них особое внимание; в устной же речи на месте тире делается пауза.

[Правила постановки тире](http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200202402)

Вот ещё примеры плакатных текстов, в которых тире поставлено для подчеркивания смысла:

Узнал фашистский стервятник, что у нас — не ягнятник!
БЕЙ ТАК: ЧТО НИ СНАРЯД — ТО ТАНК!

Answer (score 0):

Общее замечание: интонационное тире могло и может быть поставлено почти в любом месте, так что говорить об изменении норм не вижу причин.

А приведенное в вопросе предложение построено так, что это наводит на мысль об именительном темы. Другими словами, плакат сокращенно выражает такую мысль:

НАРОД, АРМИЯ, СТАЛИН — **ЭТО ОНИ** СПАСЛИ ТЕБЯ, МОСКВА!

Здесь *НАРОД, АРМИЯ, СТАЛИН* — именительный темы, а после тире тема раскрывается.

См: [ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ ПРИ ИМЕНИТЕЛЬНОМ ТЕМЫ](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=63)